# Selenium - change resolution on node service

Tags: windows, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-services, selenium-chromedriver

I am using `Selenium 3.01` on `windows server 2012 R2`.
The tests are running remotly via `webdriver`.

The problem is when a node runs as a service the resolution is too small and the tests keep failing.

When running the node as a process while logged in everything is good because the resolution is much better.

I can see the big difference when taking snaps on failure.

How can I change the resolution?

```
Driver.set_windowsize(x,y)
```

Or

```
Driver.maximize_window()
```

Are not working because the server's resolution is smaller.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Could you provide the failures you are getting in your tests as a result - are they 'element not visible' errors?

Comment: Yes those are the errors. The site requires a minimum resolution. It is not fully responsive

Comment: OK - I have had this issue myself and the only workaround I managed to find was to change how selenium interacted with elements, by using scrollIntoView. I don't think selenium can control the resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the issue.
I am using a Virtual Machine over VMware ESX.

First of all I noticed that when logging in through the console and trying to change the resolution, the maximum resolution was quite smaller than expected.

To maximize the max resolution I followed this [VMware KB](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003).

Now, change the default resolution by editing registry values:

1. Navigate to:

   `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO\{Address of primary video card}\0000\`
2. Find `DefaultSettings.XResolution` That is your X axis. Edit as a Decimal to what you want it to be. IE 1152.
3. Find `DefaultSettings.YResolution`. That is your Y axis. Edit as a decimal to what you want it to be. IE 863.
4. Restart, and you're done.

In addition, make sure your `Selenium node` runs as Local System with `Allow service to interact with desktop`.

Now you may change chrome window resolution via your code:

```
Driver.set_windowsize(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that is a service limitation, we had issue like that, solution was to start node from command line.

- Connect to remote machine
- Start node from command line
- Close connection (not by logging out, but by clicking 'X' button)

This way you'll leave your session hanging, if you want this command to be executed automatically you may try and add batch file to your startup.

Comment: That is a workaround but I am looking for a solution that will work with a service. Thank you!